# Databricks PySpark environment, find Azure storage account file path of files having same filename pattern

Tags: pyspark, azure-storage, azure-databricks

Use Case: In Databricks PySpark environment, I want to check if there are multiple files with same file name pattern existing in the Azure storage account. If they exist, I expect to get the list of file path locations for each file matched.

Tried using, **dbutils.fs.ls**, but it does not support the wildcard pattern. PFA. 
[image]

Workaround: Get paths of all files in the folder and then loop over each file to do filename pattern matching and prepare a list of required file paths.

Do let me know, if there is any other way to get the file paths, without looping over?

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks, `dbutils.fs.ls()` doesn’t support wildcard paths. This [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils) consists of all the Databricks utilies and there is no dbfs utility function that helps to use wildcard paths for matching file names.

You cannot proceed further without using loops. The following operations are done using a storage account with random files for demo. This demonstrates a way you can use to get the files that match your pattern.

Using `os.listdir()` function, you can get the list of all files in your container/directory.

```
path_dbfs="dbfs:/mnt/omega/"  #absolute dbfs path to your storage

import os

#using os.listdir() to get all files in container.
path = "/dbfs/mnt/omega" 
file_names = os.listdir(path)
print(file_names)

['country_data.csv', 'json_input.json', 'json_input.txt', 'person.csv', 'sample_1.csv', 'sample_2.csv', 'sample_3.csv', 'sample_new_date_4.csv', 'store.txt']
```

Once you have list of all files, you can use regular expressions with `re.search()` and match object property `group()` to check whether each file matches the pattern or not.

```
import re

#use regex with loops to get absolute paths of pattern matching files.

file_to_find_pattern = "sample.*csv"  #match pattern in this case.
# .* indicates 0 or more occurances of other characters, you can build it according to your requirement.

matched_files = []

for file in file_names:
    val = re.search(file_to_find_pattern,file)
    if(val is not None):
        matched_files.append(path_dbfs+val.group())
print(matched_files)

['dbfs:/mnt/omega/sample_1.csv', 'dbfs:/mnt/omega/sample_2.csv', 'dbfs:/mnt/omega/sample_3.csv', 'dbfs:/mnt/omega/sample_new_date_4.csv']
```